# Microsoft Word Dictionary Language

Tags: microsoft-word, language, dictionary

I think I may have deleted the English language dictionary. I was following directions on a website for clearing up memory issues and they recommended clearing out files with languages I do not use. Ever since then, I've had problems with Word's spell check. Even though I have set my custom dictionary to English, the advanced language settings all refer to European languages.

Almost every word in my documents is underlined and the replacement words appear to be French.

What can I do to fix this problem?

[image: Custom Dictionary English]

[image: European Language Modes]

Comment: Restore the deleted files from backup. You _did_ take a backup before you started, didn't you?

Comment: What is your operating system?